# Multicols Package - Using \raggedcolumns for some sections and \flushcolumns for others

Tags: vertical-alignment, multicol

Is it possible to have some multicols environments align using `\raggedcolumns` but others align using `\flushcolumns`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \raggedcolumns{
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $\dfrac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {{b^2} - 4ac} }}{{2a}}$
            \item $a-b$
            \item $a+b$
            \item $a-b$
            \item $a+b$
            \item $a-b$
            \item $a+b$
            \item $a-b$
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}}

    \flushcolumns{
    \begin{multicols}{3}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item $\dfrac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {{b^2} - 4ac} }}{{2a}}$
            \item $a-b$
            \item $a+b$
            \item $a-b$
            \item $a+b$
            \item $a-b$
            \item $a+b$
            \item $a-b$
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to pass the `\raggedcolumns` within the `multicols` environment for the first case. For the second one, it is not necessary to include `\flushcolumns` because that is the default behaviour

Comment: Okay fantastic, I got it to work. You have to pass it right next to the multicols environment. E.g. `\begin{multicols}{3}\raggedcolumns`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as solved in the comments.